# Symbol Table using Google Guava in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, compiler-construction, hashtable

I've done some research on Symbol Table, visually they are just hashtable with multiple values. I found an [example](https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and) online that uses libraries (*Google Guava*) however, I was wondering if using it will be efficient because values in Symbol Table usually updates for example:

```
    line 1:    VAR a = 1 AS INT
    line 2:    a = 2
```

after `line 2` `a` changes the value to 2.
As based on the example given in the link, if I have something like this `key: abc ->Apple, Aeroplane` `(values Apple and Aeroplane)`, how do I update the value from `Aeroplane` to `Orange` and get value using key?

Comment: 1. Symbol tables aren't usually MultiMaps. There's only one entry that applies to any variable at a given time. They're usually implemented as stacks of maps or, if you don't have nested scopes (or are using immutable data structures), just normal maps.

Comment: 2. This might not be relevant to you yet, but usually you wouldn't map variables to values directly (except in a constant folder). To properly handle features like references and closures (among others), in an *interpreter*, you'd want to map variables to memory locations and then memory locations to values. You could also map variables to mutable value-containers, but just to plain values isn't enough once you handle somewhat advanced semantics. And in a *compiler* you wouldn't map anything to values at all (except in the constant folder), just types and other static information.

Comment: 3. I don't understand your actual question. What do Aeroplanes and Oranges have to do with the code you posted? I mean, I realize that these are the examples used in your Guava example, so I guess my real question is: What does the Guava example have to do with what you're doing?

Comment: I would map out all the variables from given token, for example a is declared as an integer with value of 1 then the map would look like this key: a , values: int , 1. The reason is I want to map the datatype because I will use it for type checking. Btw, this is a very small compiler just to implement the disciplines in creating a conpiler. aside from symbol table how do I keep track of the values or datatypes using other techniques?

Comment: Yes, but that's one entry. You don't need a multimap for that. Also: you don't actually need to store the value for type checking, just the type.

Comment: I see, does the standard java library work with that? , can you explain what is the proper way to do semantic analysis? I’m sorry I’m still new to this and theres a lot of ideas to sync in yet I don’t know where to start.

Comment: If you have no scopes, you can just use a normal map, such as Java's standard HashMap. To support scopes, you'd usually write your own class which contains a HashMap and a pointer to the parent scope (or possibly, depending on your needs, an `ArrayList` (used as a stack) of `HashMap`s and no parent pointer). So yes, you can use the standard library for that.

Comment: Got it, I have four datatypes {Int, Float, Char, Boolean} do I have to create 4 maps like HashMap<String,Integer> , HashMap<String,Boolean> because I’m concerned that if I encounter type checking problem I might have an issue how to detect it, let’s say a is int and b is boolean, a = b - obviously it’s an error however, how do I iterate each declaration for the 4 maps to check if that variable is of the same type? or do I have a separate way for type checking alone if so do I use HashMap for type checking?can you suggest any idea for handling it.

Comment: Again: You don't need to keep track of values for type checking. What you want is an `enum Type { Int, Float, Char, Boolean}` and a `HashMap<String, Type>`. If you really do want to track more information than just the type, you'd create a class that contains the type as well as the other information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165389/discussion-between-xavier-johanis-and-sepp2k).